# How to give a optimal dBFS when I use pydub(split_on_silence) in python?

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I want to segement a audio in format of 'm4a' to use Baiduaip Best Api;
I found it really quieter because of the long distance when recording from iphone;
And I found the sys.default parameter of split_on_silence of -16.
Then the question is what is the optimal silence_thresh for by audio? Or in other words just as the question rasied.
Thanks anyone to give me a hand!

Comment: my sound.dBFS=-26